# Adobe AIR AS3: Are there limitations for "browseForOpenMultiple"?

Tags: actionscript-3, crash, air

I want the user to select several (image) files, that after the selection will be loaded asynchronously and somehow processed.

I expected I could use the standard function "browseForOpenMultiple".

But once I select more than ~ 130 files, AIR crashes with

"Process finished with exit code -1.073.740.940"

This is my test app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[

        private function onCreationComplete(event:Event):void {
        }

        private function handleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var imageFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("images", "*.jpg; *.png; *.bmp; *.swf");
            var actualFilter:FileFilter;
            var pdfBaseFile:File = new File("C:\\Users\\(userName)\\Documents\\jpgImagesDemoFolder");
            actualFilter = imageFilter;
            pdfBaseFile.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, handleFilesSelected);
            pdfBaseFile.browseForOpenMultiple("Select a file: ", [actualFilter]);
        }

        private function handleFilesSelected(event:FileListEvent):void {
            var fileList:Array = event.files;
            tiResult.text = fileList.length + " files read";
        }

        ]]></fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup width="100%"
              height="100%"
              horizontalAlign="center"
              >
    <s:Button id="btBrowse"
            label="Browse"
            click="handleButtonClick(event)"/>
    <s:TextInput id="tiResult"
                 text = "nothing read yet" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>`
```

I assume that a memory limit is hit due to that many "files to load"; although I don't need to load the files but at that moment I am only interested in the list of files.

I guess I have to read the directory programmatically (after e.g. asking the user for the directory path) and then present the result (array of file paths) to the user for selection.

Anyhow, I'd like to know if my assumption is correct and there indeed is a limit in the number of files; or a limitation in the cummulative size of the selected files.

Thanks for any clarification!

**UPDATE:**
Funnily a drag&drop of 270 files works without any problems!